# Displaying Apliction error while deploying website app using django to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I created a movie review website using  Python-Django I tried to make it live using Heroku but while opening there it is Showing  Application Error in Heroku. My app runs fine locally.

Steps I followed to Install Heroku

```
$sudo snap install --classic Heroku
$heroku login
```

And then run the following

```
$pipenv lock
$touch Procfile
```

Add the following line in wsgi file  : "
    web:gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -"

```
$pipenv install gunicorn==19.9.0
```

Changes in the settings.py

project/settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

```
$heroku create
$heroku git:remote -a xxx-yyy-26076
$heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
$git push heroku master
$heroku ps:scale web=1
$heroku open
```

Here is my code [on Github](https://github.com/AleenaShibu/moviereview).

Here is my Website link--> https://fast-island-20902.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Could you please paste some more detailed error logs?

Comment: If you had actually posted your logs, we would have seen that you have misspelled "movie_review" as "movie_reveiw" in your Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `Procfile` on the Github repository:

```
web: gunicorn movie_reveiw.wsgi --log-file -
```

I see a typo on the project name which is actually `movie_review`. Just change it and the app should run in Heroku without issues.